# How to explain the output order of this code snippet?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise, event-loop

```js
    new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        console.log('outer promise')
        resolve()
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('outer 1 then')
        new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            console.log('in promise')
            resolve()
        })
        .then(() => {
            console.log('in 1 then')
            return Promise.resolve()
        })
        .then(() => {
            console.log('in 2 then')
        })
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('outer 2 then')
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('outer 3 then')
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('outer 4 then')
    })
```

Here are my explanation:

1. Execute the `new Promise`, output `outer promise`
2. Execute the first outer then, its callback go to the microtask queue. The second outer then, the third outer then and the fourth outer then execute later, but all of their callback don't go to the queue since each promise returned by each `then` still in pending state.
3. Execute the callback of the first outer then, and output `outer 1 then`. After that, `new Promise` will output `in promise`
4. Execute the first inner then, its callback go to the microtask queue. The callback of the second inner then don't go to the queue
5. Now, the callback of the first outer then has totally finished, which means the promise returned by  the first outer then has resolved. Thus, the callback of the second outer then go to the queue
6. Execute the first task of the queue, it will output `outer  2 then` and makes the callback of the third then go to the queue. Next, execute the callback of the second inner then, it will output `in  2 then`
7. Execute the callback of the third outer then, it will output `outer 3 then` and makes  the callback of the fourth then go to the queue.
8. At last, execute the callback of the fourth outer then, it will output `outer 4 then`

Therefore, the output order should be:

```
    outer promise
    outer 1 then
    in promise
    in 1 then
    outer 2 then
    in 2 then
    outer 3 then
    outer 4 then
```

But it actually output:

```
outer promise
outer 1 then
in promise
in 1 then
outer 2 then
outer 3 then
outer 4 then
in 2 then
```

What I am confused is why `in 2 then` will output at last? And why `outer 2 then`, `outer 3 then`, `outer 4 then` will output continuously? This is different from what I have thought about event loop. I thought the result is something to do with the statement `return Promise.resolve()`, but I don't know what the statement exactly do and why it will influenced the output order.

Comment: in the first then you have to return the promise

Comment: I know,each `then` will return a promise

Comment: I'm talking about your `new Promise` call inside of the first then, if you don't return it, that then will resolve instantaneously

Comment: But here it also  resolve instantaneously  since the promise is in resolved state

Comment: No it would not. The `then` call to the promise will return a new pending promise. That will only resolve (or reject) if the callback is executed. `Promise.resolve().then(x => x) //=> Promise { <state>: "pending" }`

Comment: Yes,I know.What I mean is the code `.then(() => { console.log('in 1 then')  return Promise.resolve() })`.When execute the callback inside the `then` method,it will first log something and then return a promise.All these 2 statements are executed synchronously.And after that,since the callback has finished,the promise returned by the `then` method will fullfilled,which means the callback inside the next `then` method will go to the queue.According to this train of thought,I write down the output order above.But as you have know,it is wrong.And I don' know in which step I have made a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Before explaining the output of your code, it is important to note that real-world code **should not rely on the timing of promises in unrelated promise chains**. If you want one promise to settle after/before another promise, instead of relying on the timing in which both of them will be resolved, create a promise chain that settles the promises in a sequential manner.

Having said that, the key to understanding the output of your code is to understand how the promise returned by the nested `then()` method

```
...
.then(() => {
  console.log('in 1 then')
  return Promise.resolve()
})
...
```

is resolved.

Following steps explain the output:

1. As the executor function passed to the `Promise` constructor is called synchronously, first thing that gets logged on the console is `'outer promise'`

   ```
   micro-task queue: [ ]

   console output:
   ---------------
   outer promise
   ```
2. After the above `console.log` statement, `resolve` function is called. As a result, the newly created promise is resolved synchronously.

   This queues a job in the micro-task queue to execute the fulfilment handler passed to the `then()` method.

   ```
   micro-task queue: [ job('outer 1 then') ]

   console output:
   ---------------
   outer promise
   ```
3. After synchronous execution of the script ends, javascript can start processing the micro-task queue.

   First job in the micro-task is dequeued and processed. As a result, `'outer 1 then'` and `'in promise'` are logged on the console.

   ```
   micro-task queue: [ ]

   console output:
   ---------------
   outer promise
   outer 1 then
   in promise
   ```

   As the nested promise is resolved as a result of `resolve()` function call, a job is enqueued in the micro-task queue to execute its fulfilment handler.

   ```
   ...
   .then(() => {
     console.log('in 1 then');
     return Promise.resolve();
   })
   ...
   ```

   ```
   micro-task queue: [ job('in 1 then') ]

   console output:
   ---------------
   outer promise
   outer 1 then
   in promise
   ```
4. As the callback function of the outer 1st `then()` method ends, implicitly returning `undefined` leads to the fulfilment of the promise returned by the wrapper `then()` method. As a result, another job is enqueued in the micro-task queue to execute the outer 2nd `then()` method's callback function

   ```
   micro-task queue: [ job('in 1 then'), job('outer 2 then') ]

   console output:
   ---------------
   outer promise
   outer 1 then
   in promise
   ```
5. Next job in the micro-task queue is dequeued and processed. `'in 1 then'` is logged on the console and as the return value of the callback function is a promise, i.e. `Promise.resolve()`, the promise returned by the wrapper inner `then()` method is *resolved* to the promise returned by its callback function.

   Following code example demonstrates how the promise returned by the `then()` method is *resolved* to the promise returned by its callback function:

   ```
   const outerPromise = new Promise((resolveOuter, rejectOuter) => {
      const innerPromise = new Promise((resolveInner, rejectInner) => {
         resolveInner(); 
      });

      // resolve/reject functions of the outer promise are 
      // passed to the `then()` method of the inner promise 
      // as the fulfilment/rejection handlers respectively
      innerPromise.then(resolveOuter, rejectOuter);
   });
   ```

   This means that the outer promise (returned by the `then()` method) now depends on the inner promise (return by its callback function). A job is enqueued in the micro-task queue to resolve the outer promise to the inner promise.

   ```
   micro-task queue: [ job('outer 2 then'), job(resolve(outerPr, innerPr) ]

   console output:
   ---------------
   outer promise
   outer 1 then
   in promise
   in 1 then
   ```
6. Next job in the micro-task queue is dequeued and processed. `'outer 2 then'` is logged on the console.

   As the return value of the callback function is `undefined`, the promise returned by the wrapper outer second `then()` method is *resolved*. This enqueues a job in the micro-task queue to execute the fulfilment handler passed to the outer 3rd `then()` method.

   ```
   micro-task queue: [ job(resolve(outerPr, innerPr), job('outer 3 then') ]

   console output:
   ---------------
   outer promise
   outer 1 then
   in promise
   in 1 then
   outer 2 then
   ```
7. Next job in the micro-task queue is dequeued and processed.

   As the inner promise is resolved, a job is enqueued in the micro-task queue to resolve the outer promise. *(resolve function of the outer promise is registered as a fulfilment handler of the inner promise) (see step 5)*

   ```
   micro-task queue: [ job('outer 3 then'), job(resolve(outerPr) ]

   console output:
   ---------------
   outer promise
   outer 1 then
   in promise
   in 1 then
   outer 2 then
   ```
8. Next job in the micro-task queue is dequeued and processed. `'outer 3 then'` is logged on the console. A job is enqueued in the micro-task queue to execute the fulfilment handler passed to the 4th outer `then()` method.

   ```
   micro-task queue: [ job(resolve(outerPr), job('outer 4 then') ]

   console output:
   ---------------
   outer promise
   outer 1 then
   in promise
   in 1 then
   outer 2 then
   outer 3 then
   ```
9. Next job in the micro-task queue is dequeued and processed. This resolves the promise returned by the 1st inner `then()` method. As a result, a job is enqueued in the micro-task queue to execute the fulfilment handler passed to the 2d inner `then()` method.

   ```
   micro-task queue: [ job('outer 4 then'), job('in 2 then') ]

   console output:
   ---------------
   outer promise
   outer 1 then
   in promise
   in 1 then
   outer 2 then
   outer 3 then
   ```
10. Finally, the last two jobs in the micro-task queue are dequeued and processed one after the other, logging `'outer 4 then'` and `'in 2 then'` on the console respectively.

    ```
    micro-task queue: [ ]

    console output:
    ---------------
    outer promise
    outer 1 then
    in promise
    in 1 then
    outer 2 then
    outer 3 then
    outer 4 then
    in 2 then
    ```

Answer (score 0):

I would shove this in the corner undefined behaviour. You shouldn't rely on the internals of the JavaScript engine to execute `then` callbacks in a certain order. I can imagine two scenarios that suit the given code.

1. The inner tasks should be run before the outer tasks. Here you should make sure you return the inner promise. You can then move the inner `then` calls and add them to the outer promise chain.

   ```js
   new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
     console.log('outer promise');
     resolve();
   })
   .then(() => {
     console.log('outer 1 then');
     return new Promise((resolve,reject) => { // <- added a return statement
       console.log('in promise');
       resolve();
     });
   })
   .then(() => {
     console.log('in 1 then');
     return Promise.resolve();
   })
   .then(() => {
     console.log('in 2 then');
   })
   .then(() => {
     console.log('outer 2 then');
   })
   .then(() => {
     console.log('outer 3 then');
   })
   .then(() => {
     console.log('outer 4 then');
   });
   ```
2. You want to split off a path for the inner promise and don't care that further `then` callbacks execute before or after this separate path. The execution order between the two different paths should not be assumed. However within a path you can control the order. In the example below `in 2 then` should always be executed after `in 1 then`. The order of `in 1 then` and `outer 2 then` should not be assumed.

   ```js
   const splitPoint = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
     console.log('outer promise');
     resolve();
   })
   .then(() => {
     console.log('outer 1 then');
     return new Promise((resolve,reject) => { // <- added a return statement
       console.log('in promise');
       resolve();
     });
   });

   const path1 = splitPoint.then(() => {
     console.log('in 1 then');
     return Promise.resolve();
   })
   .then(() => {
     console.log('in 2 then');
   });

   const path2 = splitPoint.then(() => {
     console.log('outer 2 then');
   })
   .then(() => {
     console.log('outer 3 then');
   })
   .then(() => {
     console.log('outer 4 then');
   });

   Promise.all([path1, path2]).then(() => {
     console.log('path1 and path2 finished');
   });
   ```

Comment: Completely agree that we shouldn't rely on the internals of the javascript engines to execute `then()` callbacks of _unrelated_ promise chains in certain order but IMHO, intention behind such questions is to understand promises better and understand what's happening behind the scenes.