# Several separate promises with linked then(s)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I don't understand the order in which tasks are sent to the microtasks queue. 
I expected this output: `1, 11, 111, 2, 3, 12, 122` 
But received: `1, 11, 111, 2, 12, 122, 3`
Does compiler register the whole chain or it can see only the next `then`? 
How does it work?

```js
    Promise.resolve()
      .then(() => console.log(1))
      .then(() => console.log(2))
      .then(() => console.log(3));
    
    Promise.resolve()
      .then(() => console.log(11))
      .then(() => console.log(12));
    
    Promise.resolve()
      .then(() => console.log(111))
      .then(() => console.log(122));
```

Comment: The order is not guaranteed. 2 will always follow 1, as 3 will follow 2. 12 will follow 11, and 122 will follow 111. That those are you only guarantees.

Comment: Event Loop is what you are looking for!
Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Event_loop

Comment: Related: 1. [Asynchronous Execution Order in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68882535/asynchronous-execution-order-in-javascript) 2. [Promise chain .then .catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68784426/promise-chain-then-catch) 3. [How to explain the output order of this code snippet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63052649/how-to-explain-the-output-order-of-this-code-snippet)

Comment: Can you explain why you expected `3` to be logged immediately after `2`, before `12`?

Answer (score -2):

## Linked `Promise.then` calls are nested, not sequential

According to [MDN's Microtask guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide#:%7E:text=if%20a%20microtask%20adds%20more%20microtasks%20to%20the%20queue%20by%20calling%20queueMicrotask()%2C%20those%20newly%2Dadded%20microtasks%20execute%20before%20the%20next%20task%20is%20run),

> if a microtask adds more microtasks to the queue by calling queueMicrotask(), those newly-added microtasks execute before the next task is run.

However, this does not apply to linked `.then` calls. If it did, you would have to operate under the assumption that linked `.then` calls are all linked to the original Promise and not each other. You can actually see that each linked `.then` call is linked to the result of the previous `.then`:

```js
Promise.resolve(3)
  .then(x => { // Receives 3 from original Promise
    console.log(x)
    x = x ** 3
    return x
  })
  .then(x => { // Receives 27 from previous .then
    console.log(x)
    x = x ** 3
    return x
  })
  .then(x => { // Receives 19683 from previous .then
    console.log(x)
    return x
  })
```

In this example, you can see that in order for the next `.then` to be added to the queue, it needs the result of the previous `.then` call.

To further illustrate that linked `Promise.then` calls are nested and not sequential, you can create both nested and sequential microtasks to see what happens.

### Microtasks

#### Nested

When this example is run, it clearly illustrates the same results you received from linking `.then` calls.

```js
queueMicrotask(() => {
  console.log('A1')
  queueMicrotask(() => {
    console.log('A2')
    queueMicrotask(() => {
      console.log('A3')
    })
  })
})

queueMicrotask(() => {
  console.log('B1')
  queueMicrotask(() => {
    console.log('B2')
    queueMicrotask(() => {
      console.log('B3')
    })
  })
})
```

#### Sequential

When you run this example, it demonstrates the aforementioned quote from MDN. It functions similarly to how you thought linking `.then` calls would, but this is not how Promises work.

```js
queueMicrotask(() => {
  console.log('A1')
  queueMicrotask(() => console.log('A2'))
  queueMicrotask(() => console.log('A3'))
  queueMicrotask(() => console.log('A4'))
})

queueMicrotask(() => {
  console.log('B1')
  queueMicrotask(() => console.log('B2'))
  queueMicrotask(() => console.log('B3'))
  queueMicrotask(() => console.log('B4'))
})
```

### Promise conceptualization

If you don't care about this part, you can skip it. This is simply a quick implementation of a `Promise` using `queueMicrotask`. Hopefully it can help you see the nesting of linked `.then` calls and their associated microtasks.

```js
class MicroPromise {
  #result = undefined
  #thens = []

  constructor(callback) {
    queueMicrotask(() => {
      callback(result => {
        this.#result = result
        this.#callThens()
      })
    })
  }
  
  then(callback) {
    return new MicroPromise(resolve => {
      this.#thens.push({resolve, callback})
    })
  }
  
  #callThens() {
    queueMicrotask(() => { // Allows us to wait for `.then` MicroPromise constructor microtasks to execute
      for (const then of this.#thens) {
        queueMicrotask(() => then.resolve(then.callback(this.#result)))
      }
    })
  }
  
  static resolve(result) {
    return new MicroPromise(resolve => resolve(result))
  }
}

MicroPromise.resolve()
  .then(() => console.log('A1'))
  .then(() => console.log('A2'))
  .then(() => console.log('A3'))

MicroPromise.resolve()
  .then(() => console.log('B1'))
  .then(() => console.log('B2'))
  .then(() => console.log('B3'))
```

Answer (score -2):

The order of the console logs are not guaranteed. There are 45 possible outcomes each time you run your script.

Here are your rules:

- Main

  - 1 before 11
  - 11 before 111
- Secondary

  - 2 follows 1
  - 3 follows 2
  - 12 follows 11
  - 122 follows 111

### Demonstration

I put together a naïve script that will generate each permutation and validate the order based on the promise logic you have provided.

```js
const sequence = [1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 111, 122];

const rules = [
 // All Promises
 { type: 'condition', operator: 'lt', left:   1, right:  11 },
 { type: 'condition', operator: 'lt', left:  11, right: 111 },
 // 1st Promise
 { type: 'condition', operator: 'gt', left:   2, right:   1 },
 { type: 'condition', operator: 'gt', left:   3, right:   2 },
 // 2nd Promise
 { type: 'condition', operator: 'gt', left:  12, right:  11 },
 // 3rd Promise
 { type: 'condition', operator: 'gt', left: 122, right: 111 }
];

const main = () => {
  const validPermutations = permutator(sequence)
    .filter(p => validate(p, rules));
  validPermutations.forEach((p, i) => {
    console.log(`Permutation #${i + 1}: ${JSON.stringify(p).replace(/,/g, ', ')}`)
  });
  console.log('Valid permutations:', validPermutations.length);
};

const validate = (sequence, rules) => {
  return rules.every(rule => {
    switch (rule.type) {
      case 'condition':
        const
          indexLeft = sequence.indexOf(rule.left),
          indexRight = sequence.indexOf(rule.right);
        switch (rule.operator) {
          case 'gt':
            return indexLeft > indexRight;
          case 'lt':
            return indexLeft < indexRight;
          default:
            return false;
        }
        break;
      default:
        return false;
    }
  });
};

const permutator = (inputArr) => {
  const result = [];
  permute(inputArr, result);
  return result;
}

const permute = (arr, res, m = []) => {
  if (arr.length === 0) res.push(m);
  else {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      const curr = arr.slice(), next = curr.splice(i, 1);
      permute(curr.slice(), res, m.concat(next));
    }
  }
}

main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```